# Unit circle combined with angles

Tags: tkz-euclide

I've tried to make a unit circle to explain the angles, but the circle is not on the right place within the defined axes. Am I using the wrong method? Or can't I use the axis definition as in the code.
I also want the intersection of the segment and the circle to define sin and cos of the angle (but that I think I will find later with the tkz-euclide)

My code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article} % use larger type; default would be 10pt
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all} %% om allerhande objecten te gebruiken zoals gradenboog...
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,through,backgrounds,snakes}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}%
 [
    grid=major, 
    x=50mm,
    y=50mm,
    xmin=-1.1, xmax=1.1,
    xtick={-1,0,1},   
    minor xtick={-1,-0.9,...,1},
    xminorgrids = true,
    xlabel={\tiny $x$},
    axis x line=middle,
    ymin=-1.1, ymax=1.1,
    ytick={-1,0,1},
    minor ytick={-1,-0.9,...,1},
    yminorgrids = true,
    ylabel={\scriptsize $y$},
    axis y line=middle,
    no markers,
    samples=100,
    ]

 \draw[blue] (axis cs:0,0) circle[radius=1];
 \end{axis}     
 \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
 \tkzDrawCircle[R](A,5cm)
 \tkzDefPoint[shift={(0,0)}](0:5.2){B}
 \tkzDefPoint[shift={(0,0)}](50:5.2){C}
 \tkzDefPoint[shift={(0,0)}](130:5.2){D}

 \tkzDrawSegments[color = red, line width = 1pt](A,B A,C)
 \tkzDrawSegments[color = blue, line width = 1pt](A,B A,D)

 \tkzDrawPoints(A) \tkzLabelPoints(A)
 \tkzMarkAngle[fill= blue,size=2.5cm, opacity=.4](B,A,D);
 \tkzMarkAngle[fill= red,size=1.5cm, opacity=.7](B,A,C);

 \tkzFindAngle(B,A,C) \tkzGetAngle{angleBAC}; 
 \FPround\angleBAC\angleBAC{0}
 \tkzLabelAngle[pos = 1](B,A,C){\angleBAC$^\circ$ };

 \tkzFindAngle(B,A,D) \tkzGetAngle{angleBAD};
 \FPround\angleBAD\angleBAD{0}
 \tkzLabelAngle[pos = 2](B,A,D){\angleBAD$^\circ$ };    

 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I also have the problem when the angle > 180 it gives the wrong angle, because \tkzGetAngle only works in the interval -180° +180°.

[image: unit circle]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You sort of ask three quite different questions. For the first:

By default the `anchor` of a `pgfplots` axis is set to `south west`, and the position is set to `(0,0)` in the coordinate system of `tikzpicture`. You can change the position with `at={(x,y)}`, but as your circle is set around `(0,0)` that isn't necessary. You just need to add `anchor=center` to the `axis` options.

For the second:

To get the intersection between the line segments and the circle you can use

```
\tkzInterLC[R](A,C)(A,5cm)\tkzGetSecondPoint{CC} 
\tkzInterLC[R](A,D)(A,5cm)\tkzGetSecondPoint{DC}
```

`CC` and `DC` is the intersections. In the below code I've drawn and labeled those points, but I haven't drawn the lines corresponding to the sine and cosine.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone} % use larger type; default would be 10pt
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all} %% om allerhande objecten te gebruiken zoals gradenboog...
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,through,backgrounds,snakes}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}%
 [
    anchor=center,  % sets axis anchor to the axis origin
    grid=major, 
    x=50mm,
    y=50mm,
    xmin=-1.1, xmax=1.1,
    xtick={-1,0,1},   
    minor xtick={-1,-0.9,...,1},
    xminorgrids = true,
    xlabel={\tiny $x$},
    axis x line=middle,
    ymin=-1.1, ymax=1.1,
    ytick={-1,0,1},
    minor ytick={-1,-0.9,...,1},
    yminorgrids = true,
    ylabel={\scriptsize $y$},
    axis y line=middle,
    no markers,
    samples=100,
    ]

 \draw[blue] (axis cs:0,0) circle[radius=1];
 \end{axis}     
 \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
 \tkzDrawCircle[R](A,5cm)
 \tkzDefPoint[shift={(0,0)}](0:5.2){B}
 \tkzDefPoint[shift={(0,0)}](50:5.2){C}
 \tkzDefPoint[shift={(0,0)}](130:5.2){D}

 \tkzDrawSegments[color = red, line width = 1pt](A,B A,C)
 \tkzDrawSegments[color = blue, line width = 1pt](A,B A,D)


 % Finds the intersections of segments and circle
 \tkzInterLC[R](A,C)(A,5cm)\tkzGetSecondPoint{CC}
 \tkzInterLC[R](A,D)(A,5cm)\tkzGetSecondPoint{DC}

 % draw and label points
 \tkzDrawPoints(A,CC,DC) \tkzLabelPoints(A,CC,DC)

 \tkzMarkAngle[fill= blue,size=2.5cm, opacity=.4](B,A,D);
 \tkzMarkAngle[fill= red,size=1.5cm, opacity=.7](B,A,C);

 \tkzFindAngle(B,A,C) \tkzGetAngle{angleBAC}; 
 \FPround\angleBAC\angleBAC{0}
 \tkzLabelAngle[pos = 1](B,A,C){\angleBAC$^\circ$ };

 \tkzFindAngle(B,A,D) \tkzGetAngle{angleBAD};
 \FPround\angleBAD\angleBAD{0}
 \tkzLabelAngle[pos = 2](B,A,D){\angleBAD$^\circ$ };    

 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. Very pretty solution. I's typing one using `\begin{scope}[xshift=5.5cm,yshift=5.5cm]\end{scope}` to affect the second part of the code.

Comment: @Sigur don't understand your comment. Where should I put your code? As Torbjørn T. code is working for me.

Comment: @Arne, don't worry. I was saying that my solution was not so pretty. You don't need to use my code.